# Text Editor (regex?) trick to interpret a Date String

Tags: regex, string, date, editor

Take this: 20120204235900

This represents: 2012 02 04 23:59:00, or 4/Feb/2012 at 23:59:00

Well I have thousands of these and would like to change them to this: 2012/02/04 23:59:00, for example.

I know I could do a Java program but there must be an easy way to do this with some text editor.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Notepad++ you would be able to this:

```
([12]\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)
```

I check at the start for 1 or 2 to have a little bit of Date validation, if not needed then just replace `[12]` with `\d`

and replace with

```
\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:\6
```

To turn "20120204235900" into "2012 02 04 23:59:00"

The trick is to access the submatches in the brackets with the `\1` (called a backreference). So the group 1 is the content of the first pair of brackets in `\2` the match of the second pair of brackets.

With this, its no problem to reorder the submatches, but to replace the `02` with `February` a more complex logic would be needed. I think this is not possible in an editor.

Note: This is just testing for 14 digits starting with 1 or 2, so it does not verify if the digit sequence is a valid date/time!

Comment: Great, thanks. Never heard of notepad++. Unfortunately I do not have enough reputation points to vote.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Notepad++.

Just use regex replace like this:

```
([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])
```

and replace it with

```
\1/\2/\3 \4:\5:\6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *sed* (Stream EDitor), which is normally available on any *nix system. This one liner should work:

```
sed -e "s/^\([0-9]\{4\}\)\([0-1][0-9]\)\([0-3][0-9]\)\([0-2][0-9]\)\([0-6][0-9]\)\([0-6][0-9]\)/\1\/\2\/\3 \4:\5:\6/g" <filename>
```